# How to access "id" attribute of "href" element of HTML with python

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a HTMl template which has a dropdown class which further on has href for multiple choice.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
     <button class="dropbtn">Test Validation</button>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a id= 'search' href="/TEST_TYPE">SEARCH</a>
          <a id= 'logview' href="/TEST_TYPE">LOG VIEW</a>
          <a id= 'ttype' href="/TEST_TYPE">TEST TYPE</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to access these ids in python code to be able to understand from where the redirection is coming from.
I am unable to form the code in python. Please help

Comment: You cannot access the html element id from python but you can include the value of the id in the url. `href=“TEST_TYPE/search”` and so on for each option.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
What I actually want, all the options should point to one common url and that page will show the user specific filter values based on which id/any unique they have.

Comment: So basically I want to use the identification in a way that it does not change the url but based on which later on the content shown on the url changes

Comment: Conceptually, are you looking to perhaps pass the `id` on the querystring like `href="/TEST_TYPE?id=search"`?

Comment: Flask will extract the variable from the url and pass it to your route function as a parameter. See Variable Rules in the Quickstart on the flask website.

Comment: Do you mean that **when the user clicks one of these links**, you want the webserver to somehow know which `id` was clicked?  That's not possible given this HTML.  As @JonSG said, you'll have to include some kind of identifer in the actual href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, you can't access that from python. The html is executed on the user side, and  flask (python) is on the server. The only way that flask can be notified of the option clicked is by sending that information with the http request.

You can do that by using query strings as suggested by @JonSG:

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Test Validation</button>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a id= 'search' href="/TEST_TYPE?id=search">SEARCH</a>
             <a id= 'logview' href="/TEST_TYPE?id=logview">LOG VIEW</a>
                <a id= 'ttype' href="/TEST_TYPE?id=ttype">TEST TYPE</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

and then extracting that information in your flask routes as:

```
from flask import request    

@app.route('/TEST_TYPE')
def test_type():
    id = request.args.get('id')
```

(See more about it on [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#the-request-object).)

or using [variable rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) as suggested by @EAW:

```
  <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="dropbtn">Test Validation</button>
         <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a id= 'search' href="/TEST_TYPE/search">SEARCH</a>
                 <a id= 'logview' href="/TEST_TYPE/logview">LOG VIEW</a>
                    <a id= 'ttype' href="/TEST_TYPE/ttype">TEST TYPE</a>
         </div>
    </div>
```

and modify the route to expect the parameter as:

```
# We defined string  function
@app.route('/TEST_TYPE/<id>')
def test_type(id):
    `# id will have the id sent.
    return "My id is %s" % id
```

Comment: The extraction with flask solved my issue!
Thanks for the solution!